# Mogenerator - No files are generated on build

Tags: core-data, xcode5, restkit, mogenerator

I am trying to integrate Mogenerator into my Xcode 5 project. I am using RestKit along with Core Data, but the structure of my database has a tendency to change relatively frequently and I've found it difficult to keep up with these changes without something like Mogenerator.

I have followed the steps laid out in [this](http://bryanlor.com/blog/ios-tutorial-how-add-and-configure-mogenerator-xcode-5/) tutorial, but when I build the Mogenerator target, nothing happens. The Log Navigator tells me that '0 machine files and 0 human files were generated.' I have two entities created in my Core Data model, `Organization` and `Sport`, where `Organization` has a 'to-many' relationship to `Sport`.

In the 'Run Script' section of my Mogenerator Target, I have `/usr/local/bin` in the 'Shell' text box because I cannot get the Build to succeed when I have `/bin/sh` in the 'Shell' text box. I am running this script:

```
mogenerator -m Recreation2/Recreation2.xcdatamodeld -O Recreation2/Model --template-var arc=true
```

where `Recreation2` represents both the name of my project and the name of my core data model.

Why is nothing being created? And if I get to the point where something IS being created, where will it be created at?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you set the custom class name for each Entity like so in your model.  You need to make sure you change it from the default NSManagedObject or Mogen will ignore it.

[image: /Users/john/Desktop/Screen Shot 2014-05-05 at 6.04.51 PM.png]

Comment: Also you can use these arguments in the run script if you want a little more control: /usr/local/bin/mogenerator -m Recreation2/Recreation2.xcdatamodeld/Recreation2.xcdatamodel --human-dir Recreation2/Models/Human --machine-dir Recreation2/Models/Machine --template-var arc=true

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also made sure to populate that 'Class' field on each of my entities.

Comment: I also see you are missing the path to your xcdatamodel.  It should be: Recreation2/Recreation2.xcdatamodeld/Recreation2.xcdatamodel assuming that is the name of the schema you are using (default).

Comment: I feel like I'm misunderstanding what is actually happening when I type a path into the 'Shell' field. Why does it say I'm supposed to use `bin/sh`? By the way, `usr/local/bin` actually doesn't work for me - the build fails when I use this in the 'Shell' field.

Comment: Just leave bin/sh alone and paste this in: mogenerator -m Recreation2/Recreation2.xcdatamodeld/Recreation2.xcdatamodel -O Recreation2/Model --template-var arc=true

Comment: I get this error:  `/Users/Bro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Recreation2-cnakvskorabzxpamzuyufpcxtizx/Build/Intermediates/Recreation2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mogenerator.build/Script-1BA8CD6C19185B1E00618DB5.sh: line 2: mogenerator: command not found`

Comment: Sorry try this: /usr/local/bin/mogenerator -m Recreation2/Recreation2.xcdatamodeld/Recreation2.xcdatamodel -O Recreation2/Model --template-var arc=true

Comment: Or if that doesn't work, whatever the path to the mogenerator executable is.  Just hard code it for now and cleanup your path later.

Comment: FINALLY got it! Thank you for putting up with me.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Mogenerator is a godsend. :)

Comment: I'll be surprised if you're actually willing to continue this conversation, but why can't I #import one of these Mogenerator generated header files? I just added all of them to my project and then tried to #import one of them in my AppDelegate and it says that the .h file is not found...?

Comment: Unfortunately Xcode can't watch folders for files it didn't generate.  You don't need to manually add them to your Xcode project each time you build but whenever you create new ones or delete existing ones you need to add them to your Xcode project for them to show up even though they are already in the Xcode project folder structure.  Just drop them into a Models folder in your project and you will be able to import them.  BTW can you mark this question answered?

Comment: Got it. I was trying to drag the entire Models folder from Finder to Xcode.. Have to create a 'Group' in Xcode first and then drag the files. Thanks again. And yes definitely.